# problems generating interval information

Tags: answer-set-programming, clingo

Given a a binary function over time, I try to extract the information about the intervals occuring in this function. 
E.g. I have the states a and b, and the following function:

```
a, a, b, b, b, a, b, b, a, a
```

Then i would want a fact interval(Start, Length, Value) like this:

```
interval(0, 2, a)
interval(2, 3, b) 
interval(5, 1, a) 
interval(6, 2, b) 
interval(8, 2, a)
```

Here is what I got so far:

```
time(0..9).

duration(1..10).
value(a;b).

1{ function(T, V): value(V) }1 :- time(T).

interval1(T, Length, Value) :- 
    time(T), duration(Length), value(Value),
    function(Ti, Value): Ti >= T, Ti < T + Length, time(Ti).

:- interval1(T, L, V), function(T + L, V).

#show function/2.
#show interval1/3.
```

This actually works kinda well, but still not correctly, this is my output, when I run it with clingo 4.5.4:

```
function(0,b)
function(1,a)
function(2,b)
function(3,a)
function(4,b)
function(5,a)
function(6,b)
function(7,a)
function(8,b)
function(9,a)
interval1(0,1,b)
interval1(1,1,a)
interval1(2,1,b)
interval1(3,1,a)
interval1(4,1,b)
interval1(5,1,a)
interval1(6,1,b)
interval1(7,1,a)
interval1(8,1,b)
interval1(9,1,a)
interval1(9,10,a)
interval1(9,2,a)
interval1(9,3,a)
interval1(9,4,a)
interval1(9,5,a)
interval1(9,6,a)
interval1(9,7,a)
interval1(9,8,a)
interval1(9,9,a)
```

which has only one bug: all the intervals at T == 9 (except for the one where L == 1)

So I tried to add the following constraint, to get rid of those:

```
:- interval1(T, L, V), not time(T + L - 1).
```

which in my mind translates to "it is prohibited, to have an interval, such that T + L is not a time"
But now clingo said the problem would be unsatisfiable.

So I tried another solution, which should do the same, but in a little less general way:

```
:- interval1(T, L, V), T + L > 10.
```

Which also made the whole thing unsolvable.
Which I really don't understand, I'd just expect both of those rules to just get rid of the intervals, that run out of the function.
So why do they completely kill all elements of the model?

Also, during my experiments, I replaced the function rule with:

```
function(
    0, a;
    1, a;
    2, b;
    3, b;
    4, b;
    5, b;
    6, a;
    7, b;
    8, a;
    9, a
).
```

Which would make the whole thing unsatisfiable even without the problematic constraints, why is that?

So yeah ... I guess, I fundamentally missunderstood something, and I would be really greatfull if someone would tell me what exactly that is.

Best Regards
Uzaku

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The programs with constraints are inconsistent because in ASP any program which contains both the fact `a.` and the constraint `:-a.` is inconsistent. You are basically saying that `a` is true, and, at the same time, `a` cannot be true.

In your case, for example, you have a rule which tells that `interval1(9,10,a)` is true for some function, and, on the other hand, you have a constraint which says that `interval(9,10,a)` cannot be true, so you get inconsistency.

A way to get rid of the undesired intervals would be, for example, to add the extra atom in the definition of an interval, e.g:

```
interval1(T, Length, Value) :- 
    time(T), duration(Length), value(Value),
    time(T+Length-1), % I added this
    function(Ti, Value): Ti >= T, Ti < T + Length, time(Ti).
```

Now the program is consistent.

I couldn't reproduce the inconsistency for the specific function you have provided. For me, the following is consistent:

```
time(0..9).

duration(1..10).
value(a;b).

%1{ function(T, V): value(V) }1 :- time(T).

function(0,a).
function(1,a).
function(2,b).
function(3,b).
function(4,b).
function(5,b).
function(6,a).
function(7,b).
function(8,a).
function(9,a).


interval1(T, Length, Value) :- 
    time(T), duration(Length), value(Value),
    time(T+Length-1),
    function(Ti, Value): Ti >= T, Ti < T + Length, time(Ti).


#show function/2.
#show interval1/3.
```

This is what I get in the output:

```
$ clingo test 0
clingo version 4.5.4
Reading from test
Solving...
Answer: 1
function(0,a) function(1,a) function(2,b) function(3,b) function(4,b) function(5,b) function(6,a) function(7,b) function(8,a) function(9,a) interval1(0,1,a) interval1(1,1,a) interval1(0,2,a) interval1(6,1,a) interval1(8,1,a) interval1(9,1,a) interval1(8,2,a) interval1(2,1,b) interval1(3,1,b) interval1(2,2,b) interval1(4,1,b) interval1(3,2,b) interval1(2,3,b) interval1(5,1,b) interval1(4,2,b) interval1(3,3,b) interval1(2,4,b) interval1(7,1,b)
SATISFIABLE

Models       : 1     
Calls        : 1
Time         : 0.002s (Solving: 0.00s 1st Model: 0.00s Unsat: 0.00s)
CPU Time     : 0.000s
```

We are getting more intervals than needed, since some of them are not maximal, but I am leaving this for you to think about :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your answer. just adding the one line you proposed in the definition of interval1, solved the problem. But the first constraint " :- interval1(T, L, V), function(T + L, V)." works, so why does this not cause inconsistency?

Comment: Ok, I just noted, that the constraint does not work, if I define function by hand, instead of the rule, and thereby causes inconsistency. I moved the constraint to the definition of interval, adding "not function(T + Length, Value)" Which should say "There is no interval, if the next element in time is of the same value as the interval", but it still produces interval(0, 2, a) and interval(1, 1, a). why is that?

Comment: NVM, I just realized, that those are too long at the front, not at the back, so by also adding "not function(T - 1, Value)" to the definition I now have exactly what I wanted. Thanks again :)

Comment: If you add the constraint :-interval1(T, L, V), function(T + L, V), there will be no models where the constraint  is not satisfied. If you define the function "by hand", there is at most one model, where, apparently, the constraint is not satisfied, so if you add the constraint you get inconsistency. If you use the original definition of the function which uses a choice rule, the program actually has 1024 models (one model for every function), so, maybe, in some of them the constraint is satisfied, and, therefore, the program is consistent with the constraint as well.